# Umbraco 7.2.8 configuration error after nuget installation in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, nuget-package

I'm using VS2015 Community. I've created an empty ASP.NET project and installed Umbraco from NuGet package manager by following:

```
Install-Package UmbracoCms
```

During the installation I've selected to overwrite web.config and Global.asax files.
I've successfully logged into Umbraco but made no changes. Then I tried to load the default home page and I got this configuration error.

[image]

I've been looking for solution and found out that you need to upgrade your project to MVC5 when using VS2015. So I did as it is described here:
https://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2015/7/29/upgrading-your-umbraco-site-to-mvc5-and-webapi2

Sadly, I'm still getting the same config error. What might went wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Just to check the obvious: did you look in /views/web.config for duplicate elements? ;-)

Comment: Did you make sure to deselect WebForms, MVC and Web API checkboxes while creating the new empty project?
Failing to do so might include some new MVC references that aren't compatible with umbraco (depending on what version of MVC you have installed on your machine). It is better to just let umbraco include the references it needs in a completely blank project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this by installing Umbraco via Nuget in VS 2005. I’m using VS 2005, but I think the behavior would be the same for VS 2005 Community. First, I installed it in an empty project and left WebForms, MVC and Web API checkboxes unchecked while creating the new project. I built and ran the project and ran the umbraco installer. The front end loads fine.

I then tried again but this time leaving the MVC checkbox checked. I was able to run and install umbraco, but this time I got the same error you reported on the front end (root page). With this version, I see that there are 2 section groups with the name "system.web.webPages.razor” in views/web.config. I commented out the second one and I also commented out the second  in  group.  After that, the front end seems to work. I had installed the Fanoe starter kit and the pages load fine.